# how to fix hibernate exception - Don't change the reference to a collection with delete-orphan enabled

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to do a simple project which crawls the data from online shopping site using web driver, set those values to the entity and saves that entity called "product" to the database.

Hibernate throws the below exception

```
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1895) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    ... 6 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Don't change the reference to a collection with delete-orphan enabled : com.model.Product.attributes
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1490) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:515) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]
```

Here is the Product.java entity class

```
public class Product {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String category;
    private String productId;
    private String url;
    private List<Attribute> attributes = new ArrayList<Attribute>(0);
public Product() {}
// setters and getters
}
```

Attribute.java

```
public class Attribute {
    private String label;
    private String value;
    private Integer id;
    private Date createdDate;

    public Attribute(String label, String value, Integer id, Date createdDate) {
        this.label = label;
        this.value = value;
        this.id = id;
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public Attribute() {}
// setters and getters
}
```

hbm file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping SYSTEM
"classpath:///hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping default-cascade="all-delete-orphan">
    <class name="com.model.Product" table="product">

        <id name="id" type="integer" column="ID">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="productId" type="java.lang.String" />
        <property name="name" type="java.lang.String" />
        <property name="category" type="java.lang.String" />
        <property name="url" type="string" />
        <list name="attributes" inverse="true" 
            cascade="all-delete-orphan">
            <key column="attributes_Product" />
            <list-index column="SORT_ORDER" />
            <one-to-many class="com.model.Attribute" />
        </list>
    </class>

    <class name="com.model.Attribute" table="attribute">

        <id name="id" type="integer" column="ID">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <discriminator column="TYPE" type="string" />
        <property name="createdDate" type="timestamp" />
        <property name="label" type="java.lang.String" />
        <property name="value" type="text" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

cfg file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM "classpath:///hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">dev</property>

        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>

        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</property>

        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <property name="hibernate.order_updates">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.order_inserts">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>


        <mapping resource="model.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and the java code which save the data into db

```
@Override
    public synchronized void saveData(Product data) {

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction txn = null;
        try {
            txn = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(data);
            txn.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            LOG.error("HibernateException :", e);
        } finally {
            HibernateFactory.close(session);
        }
    }
```

Note : Am seting the values to the product obj before calling the saveData() method. 
the product obj will looks like follows

```
[pool-2-thread-3] EntityPrinter - com.model.Product{ productId=men-cotton-plain-charcoal-shorts,  name=Men Cotton Plain Charcoal Shorts, attributes=[], id=1, category=shorts, url=null}
```

here is the logs :

```
[DEBUG] 2019-03-25 16:00:38.413 [pool-2-thread-3] TransactionImpl - begin
[DEBUG] 2019-03-25 16:00:38.429 [pool-2-thread-3] ActionQueue - Executing identity-insert immediately
[DEBUG] 2019-03-25 16:00:38.433 [pool-2-thread-3] SQL - 
    insert 
    into
        product
        (productId, name, category, url) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?)
[DEBUG] 2019-03-25 16:00:38.481 [pool-2-thread-3] SQL - 
    select
        last_insert_id()
[DEBUG] 2019-03-25 16:00:38.485 [pool-2-thread-3] IdentifierGeneratorHelper - Natively generated identity: 1
[DEBUG] 2019-03-25 16:00:38.485 [pool-2-thread-3] ResourceRegistryStandardImpl - HHH000387: ResultSet's statement was not registered
[DEBUG] 2019-03-25 16:00:38.488 [pool-2-thread-3] TransactionImpl - committing
[DEBUG] 2019-03-25 16:00:38.488 [pool-2-thread-3] AbstractFlushingEventListener - Processing flush-time cascades
[DEBUG] 2019-03-25 16:00:38.489 [pool-2-thread-3] AbstractFlushingEventListener - Dirty checking collections

[DEBUG] 2019-03-25 16:00:38.492 [pool-2-thread-3] Collections - Collection found: [com.model.Product.attributes#1], was: [<unreferenced>] (initialized)
[DEBUG] 2019-03-25 16:00:38.493 [pool-2-thread-3] AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 0 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 1 objects
[DEBUG] 2019-03-25 16:00:38.493 [pool-2-thread-3] AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 2 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 2 collections
[DEBUG] 2019-03-25 16:00:38.494 [pool-2-thread-3] EntityPrinter - Listing entities:
[DEBUG] 2019-03-25 16:00:38.494 [pool-2-thread-3] EntityPrinter - com.model.Product{productId=men-cotton-plain-charcoal-shorts, name=Men Cotton Plain Charcoal Shorts, attributes=[], id=1, category=shorts, url=null}
```

can someone help me here to fix the above issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you able to update/get (any HQL operations)  by using this hibernate config ?

Comment: yes, I am able to update the product table. I mean the data is getting saved to the product table even though the exceptions are thrown.

Comment: please replace `HashSet` to instead of `attributes `List` ...

Comment: No, still getting the same exception.